# The JSON-RPC connection with the remote party was lost before the request could complete

Tags: visual-studio

Microsoft Visual Studio Enterprise 2019
Version 16.5.4

I'm getting this error multiple times a day with what appears to be increasing frequency.

StreamJsonRpc.ConnectionLostException : The JSON-RPC connection with the remote party was lost before the request could complete.
   at async StreamJsonRpc.JsonRpc.InvokeCoreAsync()
   at async StreamJsonRpc.JsonRpc.InvokeCoreAsync[TResult]()
   at async Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Remote.RemoteEndPoint.InvokeAsync[T]()

Nothing seems to trigger e.g. I VS can be sitting idle and the error will happen.

Comment: My VS2019 is crashing with this same error in the stack trace... Did you figure out a solution? I've tried deleting my ".vs" folder so far. Do you use ReSharper? If so, did you by chance see a mention of a corrupt "ReSharper cache"?

Comment: Not  really - turning off codelens seemed to help but only temporarily. MS claims to have fixed it in 16.6.1, working so far. I do use resharper, but I had disabled it, cleared the cash, etc... I don't think resharper is to blame... this time.

Answer (score 0):

Try to close your project. Then open it, then sign in your Visual Studio account.